# TortoiseHG Workbench command not found

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, workbench

When I installed TortoiseHg thro synaptic in my Ubuntu system, the HG Workbench was spontaneously installed into my main menu.

However, when I installed TortoiseHg thro synaptic in my debian 6.0 system, HG Workbench was not found in the main menu and neither was the thg comannd found anywhere.

The TortoiseHG version is 1.1.1-1.

How can I get to invoke the thg or workbench command in debian?

Are there additional modules I had installed in ubuntu which I did not in debian (which I might have forgotten)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my dismay, Debian is not as up-to-date as Ubuntu. And support is not as comfortable a level I have been having with Ubuntu. However, Ubuntu has become rather slow to boot up and is eating too much resources (might as well go back to Win 7). Also, Ubuntu obsessively+compulsively insists on providing horrendous desktop/colour schemes.

Answering my own question ...

The latest stable Debian is Squeeze which allows only Mercurial 1.6.4, TortoiseHg 1.1.1. Whereas, in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I am having 2.0.2, TortoiseHg 2.2.

Attempting to install Debian Squeeze backport for Mercurial 2.2/TortoiseHg 2.4 resulted in unresolved dependencies. Need to investigate if that is due to dependency on Qt4.8.

TortoiseHg 1.1.1 does not have thg workbench. It has hgtk and [hgview](http://www.logilab.org/project/hgview). I prefer thg over hgtk. To mitigate the circumstances, I installed TortoiseHg 2.6 in my Win7 Virtualbox in my Debian machine, where I would use my Win7 TortoiseHg to operate on a shared folder.  Using 2 cpu threads out of 16 for Win7 should not hurt my Debian machine very much.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian you *may have* TortoiseHG 2, where command is just `hg`